# SQLite3 and System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, android, datetime, sqlite

I want to generate exact same values using SQLite `strftime()` or any other function as that of System.currentTimeMillis() function in java. Is there a possible way ?

```
SELECT strftime('%s','now');
```

generates the current time but does not consider milliseconds but seconds. I want precision to miliseconds.

**EDIT** based on Axarydax answer

```
SELECT strftime('%s%f','now');
```

returns `129491124808.428`
where %f returning `08.428` can I round this of to `129491124808`

**EDIT 2**

```
ROUND(strftime('%s%f','now'))
```

returns 129491124808.0 I dont want `.0` at the end

Answer (score 3):

According to [this documentation](http://www.somacon.com/p370.php), formatting string %f prints fractional seconds  SS.SSS.

Comment: Thanx Axarydax, but can you help me round that of ? I want it to be exactly similar to java's System.currentTimeMillis()

Answer (score 3):

Time in seconds (epoch)

```
strftime('%s','now')
```

Current seconds + millis

```
strftime('%f','now')
```

Current seconds

```
strftime('%S','now')
```

So if you want just the millis you do:

```
strftime('%S','now') - strftime('%f','now')
```

And now add that to the time in seconds, you'll get millis as decimals

```
strftime('%s','now') + strftime('%f','now') - strftime('%S', 'now')
```

And now multiply it by 1000 and you get the current time in millis

```
CAST((strftime('%s','now') + strftime('%f','now') - strftime('%S', 'now')) * 1000 AS INTEGER)
```

Comment: This is mind boggling how this information is hard to find. Thanks man you saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(strftime('%s%f','now') as INTEGER);
```